# Does adding using statements and injections into Blazor _Implorts.razor slow loading times?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

On the Blazor website I'm building so far I'm up to 26 using statements and 30 injections in my main _Imports.razor file. Am I slowing down my website by adding all the using statements and injections into this one main file?  Is it better to add them to the individual .razor pages on an as-needed basis?

Comment: Usings are a compile time feature, so they won't slow you down. Injections on the other hand, do

Comment: Why are you injecting in your _Imports.razor file?

Comment: @Lex I guess so that I'd only have to inject once, but obviously now I'm questioning that

Comment: I would recommend only injecting things where you are going to explicitly use them.